# How to reset groupbox items?

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I wanna clean my groupbox items after i click an button.

I tried some code blocks, but they don´t work for reset controls.

I don´t wanna remove or delete it, I just wanna reset the items in the groupbox.

This is working for remove groupbox items.

```
 public void ClearPanels(GroupBox control)
    {
        control.Controls.Clear();
    }
```

or this

```
groupBox2.Controls.Clear();
```

It looks like this, before click.
[image: Before Click]

And when I click the button, as you can see on the right side.

[image: After Click]

It is removed, but I want to reset it.

Any ideas how I can do this ?

Comment: What does clear mean? Remove textbox text, uncheck everything and set combobox to the first choise?

Comment: Just replace `if` with `else if` in that answer.

Comment: _I want to clean it._ Define 'Clean' !

Comment: i would say reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to asume that clear means to leave it all by default. You need to llop all the controls inside the groupbox and depending on what control they are do something or something else.

```
foreach (Control ctr in GB.Controls)
{
    if (ctr is TextBox)
    {
        ctr.Text = "";
    }
    else if (ctr is CheckedListBox)
    {
        CheckedListBox clb = (CheckedListBox)ctr;
        foreach (int checkedItemIndex in clb.CheckedIndices)
        {
            clb.SetItemChecked(checkedItemIndex, false);
        }
    }
    else if (ctr is CheckBox)
    {
        ((CheckBox)ctr).Checked = false;
    }
    else if (ctr is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)ctr).SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

I dont know what Deneyim and Not are, but i guess you get the idea of checking what it is and asigning the value you want

Comment: How will i call this from a button?

Comment: In the same way you would call anything else

Comment: I have two buttons in my `GB` and I want only one of them to be disabled while resetting the form

Answer (score 1):

I think the term `clear` depends a little on the kind of controls you use. While for a `TextBox` you probably want to empty the `Text` property, for a `ListBox` you probably want to remove all items. So there is no common `Clear()` method for controls.

What you can do is something like that:

```
public void ClearPanels(GroupBox control)
{
    foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
        childControl.ResetText();
}
```

This iterates through all child `Control`s in your `GroupBox` and resets the `Text` property of them. You may wish to add special treatment for certain types of `Control`.

If your `GroupBox` contains nested controls (such as another `GroupBox` with further controls on it), you may need to make this method recursive:

```
public void ClearPanels(Control control)
{
    foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        childControl.ResetText();
        ClearPanels(childControl); // recursive call
    }
}
```

---

To really "clear" your controls, you have to check their specific type. So a little advanced method could be this:

```
public void ClearPanels(GroupBox control)
{
    foreach(ListBox listBox in control.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        // do more ListBox cleanup
    }
    foreach(CheckedListBox listBox in control.Controls.OfType<CheckedListBox>())
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        // do more CheckedListBox cleanup
    }
    foreach(ListView listView in control.Controls.OfType<ListView>())
    {
        listView.Items.Clear();
        // do more ListView cleanup
    }
    foreach(CheckBox checkBox in control.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        checkBox.Checked = false;
        // do more CheckBox cleanup
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Won't it clear the `Text` of all items of `ListBox` or `DropDown`?

Comment: @Shaharyar no, items in ListBoxes are no controls. `ResetText` simply sets `Control.Text = string.Empty`, but does not call something like `ListView.Items.Clear()`.

Comment: Then I would say it doesn't answer the question completely.

Comment: @Shaharyar it was just an example of how to iterate through the controls instead of removing them with `Controls.Clear()`. Anyway, added another variation, but just realized that this is indeed a duplicate.