# Auto-clearing controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to clear all `TextBox`es and `DataGridView`s in my form whenever I click on my button.

```
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Clears everything
}
```

Sorry if this is too simple I'm new to C# and to StackOverflow

Comment: To clear a textbox for example, you can just do textbox1.Text = string.Empty;

Comment: Need to write code for setting text of textboxes to blank string.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `I want to clear all textboxes and datagridviews` are any of these controls bound? If so, then you would need to target these objects, not the controls. Otherwise, please show us what you have tried, there are many ways this can be done.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069870

Comment: is this off topic??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void ClearControls()
    {
        foreach (TextBox x in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            x.Clear();
        }
        foreach (DataGridView x in Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        {
            x.Columns.Clear();
        }
    }
```

You can use this for any other controls you need as well